# Недоступны проверки после исчерпывания лимитов голосов

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Почему?

В ходе проверки я ведь могу не только голосовать за вопрос/ответ, но и редактировать, комментировать, тревогу вешать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кажется, ты немного поторопился со статусом. Посмотри комментарий к ответу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Там ничего нового: речь идёт о голосах за/против, как и обозначено в вопросе.

Comment: @404, но ведь в очередях вообще кнопок голосования нет. По крайне мере, в некоторых. Так почему же в них не пускать-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy  Речь идёт о проверках, в которых эти кнопки есть: Первые сообщения, Запоздалые ответы.  В прочих очередях отсутствие голосов за/против - не препятствие для участия.  (Но gil9red туда ещё не имеет доступа по причине недостаточной репутации).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предпочтительно поручить проверку тем участникам, кому доступны все функции проверки.

Это не значит, что другие были бы там бесполезны. Но системе нужно выбирать между проверяющим А, у которого нет голосов за/против, и проверяющими Б, В, Г, Д, у которых они есть.  Выбор очевиден.

Comment: Не знаю как другие проверяющие, но я при проверке очень редко ставлю голоса.

Comment: @gil9red, речь о голосах за/против или и о голосах по видам проверок?

Comment: @Qwertiy, за и против. Я потратил их максимальное количество за день

Comment: @gil9red,  *но я при проверке очень редко ставлю голоса* - это не то поведение, которое ожидает движок.

Comment: на большом SO новичков приучают голосовать при проверке в самой раннедоступной очереди - Triage.

Comment: @Nofate, количество голосов за день ограничено и не всем первым вопросам и ответам, которые я вижу хочется ставить какой-нибудь голос (да и не обязан), но я их ставлю (обычно вне проверки). Все-равно, не имея голоса, не иметь возможность править в проверке, странно :)